Intellisense issue when importing requests module in vscode
import sys
import requests

print(sys.executable)
r = requests.get("https://google.com")
print(r.status_code)

I wrote some simple code as above. Intellisense works well when inputting "requests.get()" while it stopped working when inputting "r.status_code". It seems like vscode recognized the type of variable "r" as "Any" instead of "Response". I'm afraid it's the reason why Intellisense didn't work when inputting "r.". I want to know how to fix it?

What tool are you using? Jedi, Pylance or something else?

@InSync I used Pylance v2024.7.1

I tried with your code and no such issues appeared. Are you using an extension like Pylance? You can use pip install requests to update the library. Install the type definition via pip install --upgrade types-requests and update the python extension. Try this and see if that solves the problem.

vs code 1.91.1;
Pylance v2024.7.1;
types-requests 2.32.0.20240712;
requests 2.32.3;
python extension v2024.12.1;
The problem was still there.

You can check if this has changed in your settings editor.quickSuggestions. and editor.suggestSelect with the option recentlyUsed. If you add from _future_ import annotations at the top, will this solve the problem?

If I added the import statement, it returned an error"No module named _future_'. QuickSuggestions was default value"other: on; comments:off; strings:off". I tried to change the suggestSelect from first to recentUsed. Unfortunately, it didn't work yet.

BTW, my python version is 3.12.4

Hello, you want to make sure that the requests library and types-requests are downloaded in the environment of the interpreter you choose. In addition, you can check if there is a requests.pyi file in the root directory. If not, you can create it in the root directory of your project.
